# CSS How to create a container with non-linear borders

Tags: css

I need to recreate a container for text that has this kind of border:
[image]

As you can see from the image the borders of the container are not straight so I have no idea on where to start.. Since the container has text inside it and the website is going to be responsive how can I possibly recreate this effect?

Can someone point me to the right direction with any hint?

Comment: Try using this: http://border-image.com/ use stretch instead of repeat.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NSm8M/2/ , here is an example as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User `border-image`

**[DEMO](http://border-image.com/#%7B%22src%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2Fqo9CL.png%22%2C%22linkBorder%22%3Atrue%2C%22borderWidth%22%3A%5B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%22imageOffset%22%3A%5B18%2C15%2C30%2C16%5D%2C%22fill%22%3Atrue%2C%22setRepat%22%3Afalse%2C%22repeat%22%3A%5B%22stretch%22%2C%22stretch%22%5D%2C%22scaleFactor%22%3A3%2C%22setRepeat%22%3Afalse%7D)**

```
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 27px;
 -moz-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo9CL.png) 27;
 -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo9CL.png) 27;
 -o-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo9CL.png) 27;
 border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo9CL.png) 27 fill;
```

Comment: This seem the perfect solution! I'll just need to find a way to support IE10, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Use a border image to render the borders.
You can use [border-image-generator](http://border-image.com/) to generate the css code easily, but the result won't be perfect, if the size of the box is bigger than the image, and the image (like yours) doesn't have repeatable parts.

The other idea is to use an SVG as a the background image / the container itself, as SVG is vector based, and can stretch, and you can define the path however you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can get as close as this using only html and css border styling.

```css
.border-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.fancy-border {
  border: 4px solid #B9C464;
  background: #DCE2B4;
  transform: rotate(0.5deg);
}
.wave-border {
  border: 1px dashed #B9C464;
  transform: rotate(-0.5deg);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.one {
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-container">
  <div class="fancy-border one">
    <div class="wave-border">Text Here</div>

  </div>
</div>
```